# Set width of div to auto inside another div

Tags: html, css, flexbox, width

I have a `div`. I want to have another `div2` with `width` to be `auto`(self-adjustable). But `width: auto` doesn’t work. `div2` needs to be aligned to the left.

```css
.parent {
  background: lightblue;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
.child {
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  ///////////
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>
    <span>
      Some text
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just **like this**, but without `width: fit-content`.

```css
.parent {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}
.child {
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>
    <span>
      Some text
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S. Cannot use `display: inline-block` for `child` div. Cannot touch/edit `parent` div, all css need to remain the same. Cannot use `width: max-content`, `width: min-content` and `width: fit-content`

Comment: display:inline-block to the div

Comment: I can’t use `display: inline-block` for `child` div unfortunately.

Comment: float:left, display:table, etc etc .. check the duplicate to find all the possible ways but you have to set a CSS to the child element